# Copy Paste with Touch

Tags: text-editor, copy-paste

I have a Samsung Galaxy S3 and I have a problem with the copy and paste feature. Since about 2 Weeks ago, I have been unable to copy by holding on the text and clicking copy. If I long press on text the blue cursor will appear, but no context menu will to allow me to copy the text.

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Have you done the usual things? Reboot the device? Clear data of the app giving you trouble? etc.

Answer (score 1):

What is your Android version?

When you highlight the text, just click the highlighted text to copy it.

Then you can paste it by long clicking on a text input field.

On Android 3+ the system changed, and you now copy and paste using the bar that appears when you long press on some text.